# Re-Assign Maximum Values in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
id OUTCOME
A    0
A    1
A    0
B    0
B    0
B    0
C    0
C    1
C    1
```

How can I re-assign the outcome values so that they are equal to the maximum value for each group? In other words, the outcome should look like this:

```
id OUTCOME
 A    1
 A    1
 A    1
 B    0
 B    0
 B    0
 C    1
 C    1
 C    1
```

I have tried doing this:

```
id_tuple = ('A', 'B', 'C')
g = df.groupby('id')
for item in id_tuple:
    new_df = g.get_group(item)
    new_df['OUTCOME'] = new_df['OUTCOME'].max()
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, new_df], axis=0)
```

This is taking a very long time, so I am looking for a better way. I appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first group by the `'id`' column, and then perform a `.transform(..)` on the `OUTCOME` column:

```
df['OUTCOME'] = df.groupby('id')['OUTCOME'].transform('max')
```

We then obtain:

```
>>> df
  id  OUTCOME
0  A        1
1  A        1
2  A        1
3  B        0
4  B        0
5  B        0
6  C        1
7  C        1
8  C        1
```